# Delete of former parent in trigger causes workflow failure on child

Tags: trigger, workflow

I have a Lookup relationship from Contact to a custom object, and an "after update" trigger on Contact that deletes any of those related objects that no longer have children.  There is a workflow rule on Contact that references fields from the parent object.  I find that when I change the related object - i.e., reparent the Contact - and the old parent is deleted by the trigger, the save fails with the following error message:

> The formula in the "TestRelatedWorkflow" rule or process is invalid due to the following:
>   The record you attempted to access has been deleted

It seems to me that the workflow rule should be referencing the new (updated) parent object and its fields, not the old (deleted) parent.  I read the [trigger order of execution document](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) carefully, and it seems to indicate that workflow rules should be evaluated after all triggers.  Am I missing something?  Is there a sensible workaround?

**Update**: this is now filed as case 09012899

Comment: Is the "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change"  ticked on the action triggered by the workflow?

Comment: It wasn't, but it is now.  No change in behavior.  It looks like that box relates to the re-evaluation of workflow rules when you change a field as a result of a workflow action, and not to the evaluation of the rule itself.

Comment: Are you able to post your trigger code to understand what it does?

Comment: Sure, why not?  [trigger code](https://gist.github.com/4063200)

Comment: And the workflow activation rule: `!TestRelatedObject__r.SomeBoolean__c
`

Comment: Please post sample code or close this out.

Comment: Hi Adam, the code is linked to in the comment two above yours, from November 13...  Would be delighted to have some help on this if you have ideas.

Comment: Is this being reparented from the standard UI, or from some apex code?  I've tried reproducing this in my dev org but have been unable to.  I was able to get the trigger to throw an error by introducing a field update to my workflow, but not the workflow rule itself.  Do you have any other workflow rules/actions or triggers on the Contact object?

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for investigating and for your comment.  It's being reparented from the UI; the trigger code (linked above) looks for parent objects that no longer have children and deletes them.  There are in fact multiple workflow rules and triggers defined on contacts in addition to the ones with issues;  if you mean to suggest one of those may be the issue I think you're right and it's worth ruling that out.  I will make a new test case with brand new custom objects and report back.

Comment: Bob, I can confirm that with Contact changed to a new custom sObject ("TestChildRecord") and the trigger moved and workflow rule moved, the same behavior occurs.

Comment: Bob, I also did the experiment of trying the same reparenting from (anonymous) Apex instead of the UI.  Result was identical.

Comment: I've performed another two experiments recently that may be interesting: 1) create a formula field on the child object with the value of the workflow rule and use that field instead of the related object reference. Result: fails the same way. 2) Defer related object delete to a @future method.  Result: success! Though this may not be an acceptable workaround...

Comment: I tried this again in Winter 14 and found that the problem has vanished.  Neither the original issue nor my simplified test case demonstrates this anymore, although previously it was easy (for me) to reproduce.  I suspect the platform has quietly been fixed, and I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Winter 14 (or perhaps Spring or Summer 13) this issue is no longer reproducible and thus the question is moot.

Answer (score 1):

The workflows fire after the triggers, but if there are any field updates that do change the values the triggers are fired again. So the triggers could run before and after workflows. Maybe use some static variable to determine if this is the first time or the second time the triggers fire.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Andres.  However, the issue is occurring during workflow rule evaluation.  The rule appears to see a situation where the parent object has been deleted.  However, the parent object is only deleted _because the child now points to a different parent_.  So an intermediate state, where the child refers to a deleted parent, should never be visible to a workflow rule or anything else.